# wrapfigure cuts off images at the end of the page

Tags: positioning, wrapfigure

I used the code from [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Wrapping_text_around_figures) to get text to wrap around images, but whenever I have a long image near the end of the page, it runs off the page and gets cut off. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When positioning the wrapped float, you can specify uppercase `L` or `R` for the position, instead of lowercase `l`, `r`. This allows the `wrapfigure` environment to float and LaTeX can move it to avoid page overflow.

Comment: Hmm, It does, but in my case it moved the figure to the end of the document, which I consider a bit excessive...

Answer (score 3):

You could add the following to your document preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\checkheight}[1]{%
  \par \penalty-100\begingroup%
  \setbox8=\hbox{#1}%
  \setlength{\dimen@}{\ht8}%
  \dimen@ii\pagegoal \advance\dimen@ii-\pagetotal
  \ifdim \dimen@>\dimen@ii
    \break
  \fi\endgroup}
\makeatother
```

and then use

```
\checkheight{\includegraphics[..]{...}}
\begin{wrapfigure}...\end{wrapfigure}
```

to check whether the image will fit on the page or not. If it does/will fit, nothing will happen. If it does/will not fit, a break (page or column) is issued, so the next paragraph will start on a new page.

The above code was taken from the minimal [`needspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace).

Comment: I don't want to be tough, but it does mean that one has to include the graphics twice, first to check its siye and then to include it?

Comment: @tohecz: That's correct. I'm not sure whether this requirement is an isolated instance, and therefore a separate commands seems viable. If not, and this check has to be included with each, it would be possible to include such a check as part of the `wrapfigure` environment.