# Lining pictures up with Margins

Tags: horizontal-alignment, margins

I am adding photos into my documents with

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.25\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{uofw}
    \caption{U of Windsor}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

but the only way I have found to line the picture up with the right margin is by adjusting the scale of the photo and adjusting the text width. Is there a way for me to have photos automatically line up with the margin so I do not have to mess around with scales?

Comment: Have you tried `\hfill \includegraphics{uofw}`?

Comment: You have to play with `\setlength{\wrapoverhang}{0pt}`

Answer (score 1):

Let me copy an answer I gave to another question https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52176/13450 and only adapt it slightly if I may:

Well, actually, I know it's not really an answer to the question but I'd try to avoid `wrapfigure` altogether. There are two alternative packages called [`picinpar`](http://ctan.org/pkg/picinpar) and [`picins`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex209/contrib/picins/). `picins` is often considered the successor of `picinpar` but I don't like it personally. In its documentation the amount of bad typography is only surpassed by the number of drop shadow effects.

`picinpar` will not solve all your problems and it doesn't support any floating as the `R` and `L` parameters to wrapfig do but it will manage decent spacing, alignment, justification and possibilities to mitigate bad luck. You can (and must) pass the number of lines above the image as an argument. The syntax is a bit cryptic but the following example might illustrate its usage (sorry it's in German), as does the good package documentation. You can also see that the alignment with the right margin happens quite naturally:

[image: picinpar usage example.]